# remove UITableCell highlight

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

how do I remove the highlight color after a UITableCell has been selected?  I am presenting a modal view over my uitableview and once that is closed the selection highlight is still there.  I remember there is a simple setting somewhere but I cannot remember it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to deselect a cell is the -deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated: method.
To use it put this code in your Table View Delegate Method (tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:):

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

You can change YES BOOL to NO if you don't want to deselect your cell with an animation.

Comment: thank you, FYI you have Rows not Row in your code above - might want to edit that for the next person.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution would be to use the `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` method on the UITableView.

See the [UITableView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ("Managing Selections" section) for the the full method signature, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Deselect cell using `-deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:` method in selection handler

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't know/care which cell is highlighted, and just want to deselect everything, you can use

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:nil animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```